# Servicenow Why can't I change Workflow of a Catalog Item?

Tags: workflow, servicenow

I am unable to change the workflow of an existing Item. For some Items I can change the workflow, for others I can't.
What might be the possible reasons? 
Tasks in progress?

What else can block me from changing the workflow? It is for for no security issue, since I am admin and have nearly all roles.

Thank you in advance. (Version is Helsinki, but also in Fuji I have this issue)

This I can't change...it's greyed out:
[image: Can't change]

This one I can change easily

[image: Can change]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you see by chance?

Comment: I added pictures. I can't change the workflow for some items.

Comment: Is it because I created the Item in the Item Designer? And got the Item Designer Workflow?

Answer (score 0):

If you had impersonated and modify/publish the workflow, the workflow cant be changed after impersonating back to your main account. To fix this you can impersonate the same user (you can find by workflow last updated) and check out to do changes. if the user has no admin roles, try giving admin roles and do the needed and strip the roles back.

Hope it would be helpful. Let me know if it resolved the issue.